# How to enforce the client to call endpoint(B) only after specific time of calling endpoint(A)

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I have two endpoints(A&B) in a Rest Controller. I'm looking for a way that I can only be able to call endpoint B after specific time of calling endpoint A. In other words I want to throw exception if anyone calls the endpoint B(get rest method) before waiting for sometime after calling the endpoint A(post restmethod), so that, endpoint A gets enough time to complete its task.

Comment: What if the server restarts after calling endpoint A? Where you want to persist this assurance that Endpoint A was called by user X at some time?

Comment: How much control do you have over the client that is making these REST calls?  Is it a service that you own?

Comment: I can recommend the solution outlined by davidxxx. Another solution would be to use a token (signed, with expiry) that is returned by A and needs to be passed to B for access control.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have out of the box solutions because that is a very particular requirement.

Using a database and particularly a key-value light-weight database such as Redis should solve your issue in an elegant way as it provides also [the `expire` feature](https://redis.io/commands/expire) :

> Set a timeout on key. After the timeout has expired, the key will
>   automatically be deleted. A key with an associated timeout is often
>   said to be volatile in Redis terminology.

You would have only the key to define and its expiration.

Using a `Map<String, Instant>` in the `A RestController` or in another bean may be tempting but we should avoid this way because it saves data on the server memory itself. 
The server should stay stateless to allow it to be horizontally scalable.